Cannot browse internet on Android 4.1 tablet
I have an old Android 4.1 tablet running on a Rockchip processor. While it’s quite slow, it still works well enough to display a clock or a web dashboard.
The problem is that I can’t browse the internet anymore. I believe this is because many modern websites (likely using CDNs and reverse proxies for load balancing) now require TLS 1.2 or 1.3, which isn’t supported by the outdated Chrome browser installed on this device. Unfortunately, I can’t update to a newer browser since they no longer support Android 4.1.
Does anyone have suggestions on how I can enable web surfing again on this tablet?

Similar problem to Proxy (or other solution) that can allow vintage browsers (before HTTPS era - with no or weak SSL/TLS support) to connect with HTTPS websites?, and is probably easier/safer if you are only running the old tablet on a WiFi you control to a proxy server running on a old PC or Raspberry Pi running on the same network.
